# Getting exception with Spring NamespaceHandler for Spring Tx

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-bean

I have facing some exception in My Spring project ..

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:data/data.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
```

application-config.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="objectMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="com.danco.citiestalking.web.jackson.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/content/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <beans:bean id="companyFilter" class="com.aap.web.filters.CompanyFilter" />

    <beans:import resource="classpath:data/data.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="classpath:data/mail.xml" />


    <!-- Ascpects  -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <beans:bean name="errorLogging" class="com.app.ErrorLoggingAspect"/>
    <beans:bean name="debugLogging" class="com.app.DebugLoggingAspect"/>
    <beans:bean name="traceLogging" class="com.danco.citiestalking.logging.TraceLoggingAspect"/>

    <beans:bean class="com.danco.apns.service.Application" id="application">
        <beans:constructor-arg type="String" value="${apns.sertificatePath}" />
        <beans:constructor-arg type="String" value="${apns.sertificatePassword}" />
        <beans:constructor-arg type="String" value="${apns.applicationName}" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.danco.apns" />
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:asdasd.properties, classpath:asdasd.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>



</beans:beans>
```

data.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <beans:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders"
                value="true" />

            <beans:property name="location">
                <beans:value>classpath:database.properties</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            order="100" />

        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <beans:property name="configLocation">
                <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="configurationClass">
                <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect} </beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>




    </beans:beans>
```

jar using

```
spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar

src/main/resource/spring/application-config.xml
src/main/resource/data/data.xml
```

Comment: Post details of your file locations & config files

Comment: I have change my question with xml

Comment: @Reimeus i have update my question with xml and jar file detail.Have you any idea

Comment: why do you mixing jar versions? are using Maven? if so post your pom.xml?

Comment: Use the version less schema (remove the `-3.2` part from the name).

Comment: @Reimeus if i convert it pom.xml then it is also not working

Comment: @M.Deinum i have also tried without this but same error

Comment: Are you sure that the jars are on your classpath? Are you using a plugin to create a fat jar?